# paramiko not executing route add (network) command

Tags: python-2.7, openstack, paramiko

I am using paramiko module with Python 2.7 to connect to remote VMs, and upload and run bash scripts. I have a new script which deletes or adds routes.

```
route add -net x.x.x.x gw y.y.y.y
```

I am getting output of all other statements except for the route that is not getting deleted.

Comment: what command are you using for deleting the route?

Comment: route del -net x.x.x.x gw y.y.y.y